# Processing weird issue with float

Tags: processing

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now to no avail. It is quite simple code, a bouncing ball (particle). Initializing the velocity of the particle to (0, 0) will keep it bouncing up and down. Changing the initialized velocity of the particle to (0, 0.01) or any decimal float will cause the ball to decrease

```java
Particle p;

void setup() {
  size(500, 600);
  background(0);
  p = new Particle(width / 2, height / 2);

}

void draw() {
  background(0, 10);
  p.applyForce(new PVector(0.0, 1.0)); // gravity
  p.update();
  p.checkBoundaries();
  p.display();

}

class Particle {
  PVector pos, vel, acc;
  int dia;

  Particle(float x, float y) {
    pos = new PVector(x, y);
    vel = new PVector(0.0, 0.0);
    acc = new PVector(0.0, 0.0);
    dia = 30;
  }

  void applyForce(PVector force) {
    acc.add(force);
  }

  void update() {
    vel.add(acc);
    pos.add(vel);  
    acc.mult(0);
  }

  void display() {
      ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, dia, dia);
  }

  void checkBoundaries() {
    if (pos.x > width) {
      pos.x = width;
      vel.x *= -1;
    } else if (pos.x < 0) {
      vel.x *= -1;
      pos.x = 0;
    }
    if (pos.y > height ) {
      vel.y *= -1;
      pos.y = height;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert in processing vectors, but I believe I've figured out why this is occurring. If you try to recreate this issue with different values of the y part of the velocity vector, you find that it only happens when the values are not multiples of .5. Based on that, this line is probably responsible:

```java
if (pos.y > height ) {
  vel.y *= -1;
  pos.y = height;
}
```

This line rounds the height of the ball, and reverses the velocity of it. This works fine when the ball hits 0 exactly and gets extra velocity before it comes back up, but when the ball goes slightly lower than it should, the velocity that comes from an extra iteration does not get added. As it happens, multiples of .5 hit exactly 0, but other values don't. My proof is that when you change the offending code to the following, every value causes the ball to fall to the ground eventually:

```java
if (pos.y >= height ) {
  vel.y *= -1;
  pos.y = height;
}
```

In short, rounding and not making the ball bounce when it hits 0 causes this issue. I hope this answered your question.